# allowed_host changes not effective

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I've got an address say example.com and have added it to the allowed_hosts list. But when I access the site I get
 `ALLOWED_HOSTS ['127.0.0.1', '::1', '178.XX.XX.XXX', 'xx80::xx81:xxx:xx3x:x12x%eth0']`

in the debug error page, while the actual settings.py file reads `['178.XX.XX.XXX','example.com']`. I figured the changes to settings.py aren't registered as I can remove `178.XX.XX.XXX` from the list and still access the site (after clearing the browser cache) I've restarted nginx, gunicorn and the whole server to no avail. The whole thing is set up on ubuntu 16.04 running django 1.8 and using nginx and gunicorn. Any ideas where this override of allowed_hosts could be coming from?

Comment: Maybe try removing all *.pyc calls in the project tree?

Comment: Besides removing *.pyc file, check to make sure gunicorn path is correct and pointing to the right application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok this is embarassing but the One-cick install for django on 16.04 from Digital Ocean adds a line at the very end of `settings.py` where `ALLOWED_HOSTS` is redefined.

```
# Find out what the IP addresses are at run time
# This is necessary because otherwise Gunicorn will reject the connections
def ip_addresses():
    ip_list = []
    for interface in netifaces.interfaces():
        addrs = netifaces.ifaddresses(interface)
        for x in (netifaces.AF_INET, netifaces.AF_INET6):
            if x in addrs:
                ip_list.append(addrs[x][0]['addr'])
    return ip_list

# Discover our IP address
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ip_addresses()
ALLOWED_HOSTS.append('.example.com') #I added this line
```

So adding an append to the line fixes the problem.

Comment: I ran into this issue as well. Is this the right place to put this or do the the allowable domains belong upstream somewhere that that server manages and passes down to the Django?